# Testing a coefficient is significantly different from 1

Tags: stata

There are stackexchange posts on this from purely methodological point of view ([Testing whether the regression coefficient is significantly less than 1 (one-tailed t-test)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542744/testing-whether-the-regression-coefficient-is-significantly-less-than-1-one-tai)) or from R (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111559/test-model-coefficient-regression-slope-against-some-value). However, I couldn't find Stata example.

After running a regression, how can I test if the coefficient is significantly different from 1?

Comment: In Stata read `help test`. The very first example is testing a regression coefficient.

Comment: @NickCox   I read it but it seems to only say about testing H0:beta=0. "Syntax 1 tests that coefficients are 0." Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Indeed, as you need to specify 1 not 0.